# the cause for increasing of memory usage in each step in the loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve a system of equations using a function that I defined myself. The problem is that the memory usage increases in every step and after a period of time for example after 100 steps in the loop, the programme breaks due to memory usage. 
I am not defining new parameters in each step, and I just replace the value of the parameters with new calculated values.

Is there any idea to solve this issue?

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void NAPLConcentration(int n, int m, double* P, double* C, double* D, double* Tx, double* Ty, double* R);

int main()
{
    int i, n = 2500, m = 1000;
    double *P, *C, *D, *Tx, *Ty, *R;
    P = new double[n*m];
    C = new double[n*m];
    D = new double[n*m];
    Tx = new double[n*m];
    Ty = new double[n*m];
    R = new double[n*m];

    for (i = 0; i < n*m; i++)
    {
        P[i] = 70;
        C[i] = 0.5;
        Tx[i] = 0.01;
        Ty[i] = 0.02;
        R[i] = 0.1;

    }


    for (i = 0; i<10000000; i++)
        NAPLConcentration(n, m, P,  C,  D,  Tx,  Ty,  R);


    delete[] P;
    delete[] C;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

void NAPLConcentration(int n, int m, double* P, double* C, double* D, double* Tx, double* Ty, double* R)
{
    int i;
    double W, E, N, S;
    double *CNew;
    CNew = new double[n*m];                                     


    for (i = 2; i<n*m-2; i++)
    {
        E = 2 * Tx[i] * Tx[i + 1] / (Tx[i] = Tx[i + 1]);        // the harmonic average of transmissibility of NAPL between ith and (i+1)th in x direction 
        W = 2 * Tx[i] * Tx[i - 1] / (Tx[i] = Tx[i - 1]);          // the harmonic average of transmissibility of NAPL between ith and (i-1)th in x direction
        N = 2 * Ty[i] * Ty[i +2] / (Ty[i] + Ty[i +2]);        // the harmonic average of transmissibility of NAPL between ith and (i+m)th in y direction, north side of thegrid block
        S = 2 * Ty[i] * Ty[i - 2] / (Ty[i] + Ty[i - 2]);          // the harmonic average of transmissibility of NAPL between ith and (i-m)th in y direction, south side of thegrid block

        CNew[i] = (E*(P[i + 1] - P[i])*C[i] - W*(P[i] - P[i - 1])*C[i] + N*(P[i] - P[i])*C[i] - S*(P[i] - P[i])*C[i] + R[i] ) / D[i] + C[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i<n*m; i++)
        C[i] = CNew[i];

}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: You need to add the implementation for `NAPLConcentration` to figure out what might be going wrong.

Comment: `double pressure, CNAPL;` are just variables on the stack and not pointers.... you are doing a new on them? thats undefined behaviour.

Comment: @SamerTufail: no, that's a compilation error.

Comment: I forgot to put * in this post but I did in my code before.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I thought so too, but since it was posted as working code, might be a compiler which lets this through.

Comment: as I said it run for example until i=1000; but after I got an error for memory usage. what is the problem

Comment: @Mortezaaminnaji: no one is going to / is able to help you until you post a [MCVE].

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo, OK I am trying to post the code but the code is very too large

Comment: I put an example of code that causes the increase in memory usage in every step. is there any comments @Vittorio Romeo, @ Samer Tufail

Comment: `CNew = new double[n*m]` in `NAPLConcentration` but no `delete[]`? Use `std::vector<double>(n*m)`  instead.

Comment: Thanks every one. it is solved now. I forgot to put delete[] for CNew.

Answer (score 2):

From the updated code snippet I can see that you're allocating memory for `CNew` but never releasing it. You need to call `delete[]` to release that memory.

Anyway, you should not use `new`/`delete` in C++11 and above – look into *containers* such as `std::vector`<sup>1</sup>. They would have prevented your issue without sacrificing performance.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Or *smart pointers* such as `std::unique_ptr` if you need more flexbility.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Every time `NAPLConcentration` is called, the memory allocated is 2500 * 1000 * 8 bytes (Assuming size of double is 8 bytes). This is about 19 MB.

When `NAPLConcentration` is called a 100 times, the total memory allocated by this function alone will be 1.9 GB because the memory is not deleted at the end of the function.

So delete the memory allocated in the function after the required processing is done.

To avoid memory handling yourself, you can use STL containers. In this case you can go for a Dynamic contiguous array like `vector`.

Comment: *"In this case you can go for a Dynamic contiguous array like vector."* Not just *can*, but definitely *should*! Even if there is any reason left to use `new[]`, this is not it.

Comment: We do not know what constraints the asker is under,  whether he is allowed to use STL or not. So we can only make suggestions, not make it mandatory. :-)